# What are the benefits of using a software RSS reader versus an online source?

Tags: windows, linux, rss, web

I've been using online RSS readers for a long time, but was never able to find a single service that gave me everything I wanted.  I've reviewed the answers on this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1979/what-rss-readers-do-you-use) and figured that I would give a software RSS reader a try.

However, what are the pros or cons of using software instead of webware? I know the obvious RAM and CPU usage, but is it that significant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One pro is that you can access your feeds offline, read everything you want, and when you go online, It'll (if that program supports it) synchronize. I use Google Reader, I've tried from Thunderbird to FeedDemon, but I prefer GReader, because I read frequently from the original page, not the text that it gives me.